# Jumpy scroll to section with offset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using small jQuery script to scroll to section with id corresponding clicked a tag's href.

For example, after clicking `<a href="#section1">scroll to section1</a>` user window will go to target section with `id="section1"` with animation.

With standard settings everything works just fine, but after applying offset, animation starts to get jumpy in last stage of scroll.

Here is part of code online:
https://codepen.io/engray/pen/WMaXev

I tried changing offset value to predefined value, but it didn't help at all. Do you have any idea, what may be causing animation jumpy effect?

Comment: In case you are looking for a more complete solution you could try [fullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to repair this weird behavior, thanks to: [Jack Hair's answer at original css-tricks.com post](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/#comment-1612963). Turns out, that newest Chrome version is causing problems with focused element

[Peter](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/#comment-1612432) says:
*It sounds like in the newest version of Chrome there is a bug that causes the scroll to jump if you have an offset (for a fixed navbar).*

Below solution by [Jack Hair](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/#comment-1612963):

```
// fix chrome of focus scroll
    $.fn.focusNoScroll = function() {
        var x = window.scrollX,
            y = window.scrollY;
        this.focus();
        window.scrollTo(x, y);
        return this;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add `headerHeight` to your `targetOffest` as the navbar is fixed:

```
var targetOffest = target.offset().top  + headerHeight
```

Using only `target.offset().top` as parameter should work.
*Note: The [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)s `scrollTop` will make the top of the div scroll to the top of the page, your code makes it scroll to the bottom of the navbar as you were adding the header height.*

```js
$('a[href*="#"]').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
  var targetOffest = target.offset().top;
  var headerHeight = document.getElementByClassName('navbar')[0].offsetHeight;
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: targetOffest
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.navbar ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar ul li a{
  color: white;
}

.section{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

#section1{
  background: red;
}

#section2{
  background: blue;
}

#section3{
  background: green;
}

#section4{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#section1">s1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">s2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">s3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section4">s4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="section" id="section1"></div>
<div class="section" id="section2"></div>
<div class="section" id="section3"></div>
<div class="section" id="section4"></div>
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

After setting the attribute `tabindex` the div will roll to the top, you can set the position of scroll again with [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [.scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo):

```
var x = $(window).offset().top,
    y = $(window).offset().left;
$target.attr('tabindex', '-1');
$target.focus();
$(window).scrollTo(x, y);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer! Unfortunately, adding headerHeight offset is vital in this code. Final website has background without transparency and that's why I'm adding offset. Without such offset, fixed navbar was sometimes covering section content.

Comment: _Note: The .animate()s scrollTop will make the top of the div scroll to the top of the page, your code makes it scroll to the bottom of the navbar as you were adding the header height._ that's why I'm adding this offset, so that window is scrolled to scrollTop of div minus headerHeight

Comment: The problem, then, is with this line: `$target.attr('tabindex', '-1');`.

Comment: @kl yes, you're right, I've managed to find out by myself, nevertheless thank you for your time! For details pls check my answer below

Comment: That's fine! Good job! :)